# Recursively dividing a list into sublists based on a predicate

Tags: python, list, recursion

As I was studying towards and python exam, I found this problem where it wants me to create a fully recursive function `cut_sequence_recursively(seq, pred)` thats takes a sequence (list of numbers) and returns a list containing the original sequence but divided into sublists. 
The sequence is to be divided into a new sublist each time a number of the sequence fulfill the predicate.
This is to be done in a way that satisfy the following `asserts`:

```py
assert cut_sequence_recursively([], lambda x: x % 2 != 0) == [[]]
assert cut_sequence_recursively([1,2,3,4], lambda x: x % 2 != 0) == [[1,2],[3,4]] 
assert cut_sequence_recursively([4,2,3,4,8,12,5,2,1], lambda x: x % 2 != 0) == [[4,2], [3,4,8,12], [5,2], [1]]
```

Solving it iteratively seems quite easy however I cannot for the life of my figure how to approach this one, so any help or insights would be extremely helpful!

Comment: Try writing out the iterative version first.

Comment: You could start by iterating the list recursively. After that, try to accumulate arbitrary sublists onto a result list. Then add the predicate. This is too broad without an attempt and evaluates to "code it for me" rather than "help me fix my implementation attempt". Also, this is a poor fit for recursion without TCO because the subproblems only shorten the tail list by 1 element. You can easily blow the stack if your list is more than 1000 elements or so.

Comment: you have inconsistency in the output. the first problem asks to cut an empty but the result contains empty "slices". in the second problem `1` marks the first cut but doesn't return the empty slice that appears before the `1`. i would expect `[[],[1,2],[3,4]]` as the answer for the second problem. if that is incorrect, i would expect `[]` as the answer to the first problem. it doesn't make sense as it is currently stated

Comment: To add to inconsistency, take a look at the last one. Why would `[3,4,8,12]` not be split into `[3,4], [8], [12]`? And why would `[4,2]` not get split into `[4], [2]`?

Comment: Is the goal to go until the predicate does **not** match?

Comment: @Chrispresso my understanding was that it should slice up to the element that returns true for the predicate, `x`, and then start a new slice containing `x`. but yeah, who knows?

Comment: @Thankyou yes, that is the idea as i understood the problem. However anserwing your first remark; I belive the goal was to create a function which output was a main list containing lists which we get through the slicing process you described to Chris. This is why we get [[]] in the first case since the outer list is the main list that contains the "output" of our slicing and since its a empty list we cant slice it anywhere. As to the secound case I dont simply know why it supossed to be like that.

Comment: @ggorlen I will try something in that style! I apolegise if you found my question vauge or "needy" this was a coding problem i found while looking through old coding exams in my course, The question was quite vauge so therefor my vauge question here, will definitly try to improve if i ever ask anything in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplified `cut` with consistent output -

```py
def cut(t, p):
  def loop(t, r):
    if not t:
      yield r
    elif p(t[0]):
      yield r
      yield from loop(t[1:], [t[0]])
    else:
      yield from loop(t[1:], [*r, t[0]])
  return list(loop(t, []))
```

```py
print(cut([], lambda x: x % 2 != 0))
print(cut([1,2,3,4], lambda x: x % 2 != 0))
print(cut([4,2,3,4,8,12,5,2,1], lambda x: x % 2 != 0))
```

```py
[[]]
[[], [1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[4, 2], [3, 4, 8, 12], [5, 2], [1]]
```

A complex variant of `cut` that matches the complex requirements of your question -

```py
def cut(t, p):
  def loop(t, r):
    if not t:
      yield r
    elif not r:
      yield from loop(t[1:], [t[0]])
    elif p(t[0]):
      yield r
      yield from loop(t[1:], [t[0]])
    else:
      yield from loop(t[1:], [*r, t[0]])
  return list(loop(t, []))
```

```py
print(cut([], lambda x: x % 2 != 0))
print(cut([1,2,3,4], lambda x: x % 2 != 0))
print(cut([4,2,3,4,8,12,5,2,1], lambda x: x % 2 != 0))
```

```py
[[]]
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[4, 2], [3, 4, 8, 12], [5, 2], [1]]
```

Finally a variation of `cut` that does not use generators -

```py
def cut(t, p, r = []):
  if not t:
    return [r]
  elif not r:
    return cut(t[1:], p, [t[0]])
  elif p(t[0]):
    return [ r, *cut(t[1:], p, [t[0]]) ]
  else:
    return cut(t[1:], p, [*r, t[0]])
```

```py
print(cut([], lambda x: x % 2 != 0))
print(cut([1,2,3,4], lambda x: x % 2 != 0))
print(cut([4,2,3,4,8,12,5,2,1], lambda x: x % 2 != 0))
```

```py
[[]]
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[4, 2], [3, 4, 8, 12], [5, 2], [1]]
```

---

**different names for the same thing**

All of these programs function in the same way but all of them suffer some readability issues. If we give names to `t[0]` and `t[1:]` it makes it much easier to see what's actually going on -

```py
def first (t):
  return t[0]

def rest (t):
  return t[1:]
```

A rewrite of `cut` using generator-based approach -

```py
def cut(t, p):
  def loop(t, r):
    if not t:
      yield r
    elif not r:
      yield from loop(rest(t), [first(t)])
    elif p(first(t)):
      yield r
      yield from loop(rest(t), [first(t)])
    else:
      yield from loop(rest(t), [*r, first(t)])
  return list(loop(t, []))
```

And a rewrite of `cut` without using generators -

```py
def cut(t, p, r = []):
  if not t:
    return [r]
  elif not r:
    return cut(rest(t), p, [first(t)])
  elif p(first(t)):
    return [ r, *cut(rest(t), p, [first(t)]) ]
  else:
    return cut(rest(t), p, [*r, first(t)])
```

Finally, if you don't like defining `first` and `rest` as separate functions, you can add a bit of inline boilerplate -

```py
def cut(t, p, r = []):
  if not t:
    return [r]
  else:
    (first, *rest) = t                 # <- "first" and "rest"
    if not r:
      return cut(rest, p, [first])
    elif p(first):
      return [ r, *cut(rest, p, [first]) ]
    else:
      return cut(rest, p, [*r, first])
```

Feel free to ask any questions

Comment: ! It works like magic!  Could you elaborate it to make it easier to follow?  Thanks!

Comment: Daniel I cleaned up the examples a bit and adding a section on naming things that helps increase readability of python programs. Please let me know if these help :)

Comment: Now, I could follow the `thoughts`.  Thanks.  `The Readability counts!` :-)